# I have a problem with understanding the event system

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this code:

```js
<template>

  <div class="chart"
       v-bind:style="chartStyleObject"
       v-on:mousedown.left="initHandleMousedown($event)"
       v-on:mouseup.left="initHandleMouseup()"
       v-on:mouseout="initHandleMouseup()">

    <div class="chartContent">
    </div>
    <!--   <div class="chartContent">  end   -->

  </div>
  <!--   <div class="chart">   end   -->

</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

export default{

created () {
},

data () {
  return {
    ticket: null,

    chartStyleObject: {
      width: '500px',
      widthWrapper: '1600px',
      heightWrapper: '500px',
      height: '247px',
      marginTop: '15px',
      marginRight: '0px',
      marginBottom: '0px',
      marginLeft: '15px',
    },

    XCoord: null,
    YCoord: null,

  }
},

methods: {

  initHandleMousedown(event) {
    this.startMousedownXCoord = event.clientX;
    this.startMousedownYCoord = event.clientY;
    this.XCoord = event.clientX;
    this.YCoord = event.clientY;

    console.log('XCoord', this.XCoord);
    console.log('YCoord', this.YCoord);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.initHandleMouseMove);
  },

  initHandleMouseMove(event) {

      this.XCoord = event.clientX;
      this.YCoord = event.clientY;

      console.log('XCoord', this.XCoord);
      console.log('YCoord', this.YCoord);

  },

  initHandleMouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.initHandleMouseMove);
  },

  },

}

</script>

<style scoped>

.chart{
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 27px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #45788b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
}
.chart .chartContent{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #2f2c8b;
}



</style>
```

```
HTML design consists of 2 blocks:
(parent and child)
The event is tied to the parent tag `<div class =" chart ">`
Also, the parent block has padding on all 4 sides:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

If you click on the parent block and drive with the mouse (holding the button pressed) without affecting the padding space, the mousemove event will fire without problems.
But as soon as the mouse cursor touches the padding territory, the event ceases to function. 
If you click on the padding, the event also works correctly - but it stops working if I move the mouse cursor over the block space outside the paddings (internal space) 
Question: 
Why is this happening - and is this behavior normal for js + nuxt.js?

Comment: @Alex Could you elaborate on exactly what the bounty is for? If you just wanted some links to the relevant sections on MDN you could've just posted a comment on my answer so I assume you're looking for something a bit more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't exactly follow your descriptions of the various regions of the page but I can have a go at explaining what I think you're seeing.

The key to this is that you have a `mouseout` listener that removes your `mousemove` listener. The `mouseout` event propagates, which means it will fire even if the `mouseout` occurred on a child element. Contrast with `mouseleave` which will only fire if the event occurs on the element itself.

The example below illustrates how a `mouseout` listener will fire even if the mouse cursor doesn't leave the root element. Just moving the cursor outside a child is sufficient.

```js
document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += 'mouseout\n'
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div></div>
</div>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

I suspect that when you observe the event ceasing to function what is actually happening is that a `mouseout` event is occurring and that is removing the `mousemove` listener.

Answer (score 1):

skirtle answer is correct. I am only providing this answer to illustrate how to do it using your own code. The only line I changed was this `v-on:mouseleave="initHandleMouseup()`. Notice I changed it to mouseout to mouseleave.

To summarize:

- `mouseleave` is fired once per element regardless of its children
  hover.
- `mouseout` is fired every time the element abandoned (whether
  moving the mouse away or hovering over its children).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `

  <div class="chart"
       v-bind:style="chartStyleObject"
       v-on:mousedown.left="initHandleMousedown($event)"
       v-on:mouseup.left="initHandleMouseup()"
       v-on:mouseleave="initHandleMouseup()">

    <div class="chartContent">
    </div>
    <!--   <div class="chartContent">  end   -->

  </div>
  <!--   <div class="chart">   end   -->

`,
  created: function() {},

  data() {
    return {
      ticket: null,

      chartStyleObject: {
        width: '500px',
        widthWrapper: '1600px',
        heightWrapper: '500px',
        height: '247px',
        marginTop: '15px',
        marginRight: '0px',
        marginBottom: '0px',
        marginLeft: '15px',
      },

      XCoord: null,
      YCoord: null,

    }
  },

  methods: {

    initHandleMousedown: function(event) {
      this.startMousedownXCoord = event.clientX;
      this.startMousedownYCoord = event.clientY;
      this.XCoord = event.clientX;
      this.YCoord = event.clientY;

      console.log('XCoord', this.XCoord);
      console.log('YCoord', this.YCoord);

      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.initHandleMouseMove);
    },

    initHandleMouseMove: function(event) {

      this.XCoord = event.clientX;
      this.YCoord = event.clientY;

      console.log('XCoord', this.XCoord);
      console.log('YCoord', this.YCoord);

    },

    initHandleMouseup: function() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.initHandleMouseMove);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 27px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #45788b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
}

.chart .chartContent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #2f2c8b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

To see the different between `mouseout/mouseover` vs `mouseenter/mouseleave` events see this demo (taken from [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)) :

```js
var i = 0;
$("div.overout")
  .mouseout(function() {
    $("p", this).first().text("mouse out");
    $("p", this).last().text(++i);
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    $("p", this).first().text("mouse over");
  });

var n = 0;
$("div.enterleave")
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("p", this).first().text("mouse enter");
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("p", this).first().text("mouse leave");
    $("p", this).last().text(++n);
  });
```

```css
div.out {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: #d6edfc;
  float: left;
}

div.in {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #fc0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

p {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="out overout">
  <p>move your mouse</p>
  <div class="in overout">
    <p>move your mouse</p>
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <p>0</p>
</div>

<div class="out enterleave">
  <p>move your mouse</p>
  <div class="in enterleave">
    <p>move your mouse</p>
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <p>0</p>
</div>
```